# Angular Router outlet not rendering

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Having issues with router-outlet not rendering the page.

The app.module imports RouterModule and RouterOutlet.

The app-routing.module.ts consists of the following code.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' }
];

export default routes;

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

The problem comes when I put  in app.component.html. It throws an error saying that

```
"Error: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead."
```

I can link to the app-home component and it works just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: please share app.module.ts and app.component.ts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BrowserModule` or `BrowserAnimationsModule` should be imported once in app.module. In submodules or components, you need to remove the `BrowserModule` or `BrowserAnimationsModule` from imports.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for trying to help me out. As it turns out, BrowserModule cannot be imported more than once in the entire app.

So I imported Browser module only in the app.module and then replaced the other imports of BrowserModule with CommonModule and everything clicked.

Hope this helps anyone else out who encounters this error.